# Flask cannot import from website create_app

Tags: python, flask

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'website'
```

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whether you want a file that can be run as the main program or imported by other modules. We can use an

`if __name__ == "__main__"` block

to allow or prevent parts of code from being run when the modules are imported.

When the Python interpreter reads a file, the **name** variable is set as **main** if the module being run, or as the module's name if it is imported. Reading the file executes all top level code, but not functions and classes (since they will only get imported).

Sample code of flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I believe your the fault is instead of **name** == "**main**", you put name == main

Answer (score 1):

you should put **init.py** under **website** folder, not inside any folder else like **static** or **templates** folders

like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run your `__init__.py` file,
Then run the main.py file
Hope it helps:)